# Ignore null values in context update

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, null, entity-framework-5

I have a large model which has been partially updated via deserialization.  Since it has only been partially updated I would like to ignore any null values when I pass this to my entity framework update.  Ultimately the `EntityState.Modified` is set but the issue I am having is that all fields are updated.  This means anything that was null is now blanked in the database.
Is it possible to change this default behavior through a setting or override a method to check for null?  It seems that since the context is expecting the full model I cannot simply set only a few values.
I've verified this by mapping only what I need to modify and the same behavior occurs.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement something like this.

In this case I'm using a generic repository with reflection, to iterate through the properties and exclude null values in the update method.

```
public virtual TEntity Update(TEntity entity)
{
    dbSet.Attach(entity);
    dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

    var entry = dbContext.Entry(entity);

    Type type = typeof(TEntity);
    PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        if (property.GetValue(entity, null) == null)
        {
            entry.Property(property.Name).IsModified = false;
        }
    }

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
    return entity;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how to consume this generic method!

Answer (score 2):

```
 public IHttpActionResult PutProduct(int id, Product product)
    {
        NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Products.Attach(product);

        // Only the fields you want to update, will change.
        db.Entry(product).Property(p => p.ProductName).IsModified = true;
        db.Entry(product).Property(p => p.UnitPrice).IsModified = true;
        db.Entry(product).Property(p => p.UnitsInStock).IsModified = true;

        //  only if if the value is not null, the field will change.
        db.Entry(product).Property(p => p.UnitsOnOrder).IsModified = 
        product.UnitsOnOrder != null;

        db.SaveChanges();


        return Ok(product);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat tedious problem I've had to solve.

For lack of a more straightforward solution, eventually I decided I'd rather not want to try solving it as much downstream as when EF's SaveChanges-and-the-likes' get called (i.e., no need to "hook into" EF so late), but instead as much higher upstream / earlier on as possible --

that is, to do so right after I obtain a satisfying deserialization, which is meaningful to mutate the model, on a per-entity instance basis (in my use case, none of the updatable properties would represent relationships, but only independent attributes, in E/R parlance -- YMMV)

So, I opted for a "Populate" helper, along the lines of:

```
    static void Populate(object from, object to)
    {
        var sourceType = from.GetType();
        foreach (PropertyInfo target in to.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            // Is the property at the target object writable and *not* marked
            // as `[NotMapped]'?
            var isUpdatable =
                target.CanWrite &&
                (target.GetCustomAttribute<NotMappedAttribute>(true) == null);
            if (isUpdatable)
            {
                // If so, just find the corresp. property with the same name at the source object
                // (caller is assumed responsible to guarantee that there is one, and of the same type, here)
                var source = sourceType.GetProperty(target.Name);

                var @default = sourceType.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(sourceType) : null;
                var equality = (IEqualityComparer)typeof(EqualityComparer<>).MakeGenericType(sourceType).GetProperty("Default", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null);
                var value = source.GetValue(from);

                // Test for <property value> != default(<property type>)
                // (as we don't want to lose information on the target because of a "null" (or "default(...)") coming from the source)
                if (!equality.Equals(value, @default))
                {
                    target.SetValue(to, value, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

where "from" is the fresh entity instance that just got partially populated by whatever deserialization code, and where "to" is the actual target entity that lives in the DbContext (be it an EF proxy or not);

and where [NotMappedAttribute](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/notmapped-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) is the EF's usual.

You'd typically have Populate to be called some time after the deserialization (&/or DTO-mapping) onto your "from" instance is done, but anyway before SaveChanges() gets call on your DbContext for all the "to" entities -- obviously, we assume there is a feasible 1-to-1 mapping "from" ... "to", that the caller of Populate knows about / could figure out.

Note I still don't know if there is a more elegant (more straightforward) way to do that, without recourse to reflection -- so, there, FWIW.

Remarks

1) above code can (or should) be made more defensive in various ways, depending on the caller assumptions;

2) one may want to cache those IEqualityComparer's (&/or the PropertyInfo's) for whatever (good) reason may arise -- in my case, I didn't have to;

3) finally, my understanding is that third-party librairies such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) are also specially designed for that sort of task, if you can afford the additional dependency

'HTH,

Comment: I do have something very similiar in that I've created a Mapping Factory that is responsible for mapping between the various layers of the infrastructure (eg. API->Business->Data).  I appreciate that Reflection isn't a great option for you either.  I don't think it makes sense in this instance either.  Also, my workgroup had reviewed AutoMapper but rejected it due to other reasons.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: 'welcome & well, yes, besides using something like AutoMapper or reflection, I wish I had found something else that wouldn't require hacking into EF, but still, the above helper does the job just fine so far in my case. Anyway I made sure it could be used in a central, easy-to-refactor location (should I need to do that differently).

Comment: After review this code works well (minus a couple null checks) but maybe I'm misunderstanding something?  The resultant model that I'm mapping to the database (`to` in this case) still contains all the mapped properties of the model after the reflection, which means the nulls are still causing problems at the datalayer.  Ultimately I need to remove all properties that contain nulls.

Comment: The actual value of the "to" formal argument is an instance of an entity already loaded in the DbContext, e.g., an item of some DbContext.Set<T>'s IQueryable selection; only the "from" argument is the one referencing a new entity partially initialized with some deserialization or mapping from a DTO.

Answer (score 0):

I was stumbling on @Carlos Gregorio's Answer Regarding the use of **TEntity!**

Eventually found that TEntity must inherit class or base class on class declaration!

```
public class DBContextService<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
... ... ...
    public virtual TEntity Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entity);
        dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    ... ... ...
    }
}
```